# Dynamics CRM - Trigger Plugin on change of actualend

Tags: plugins, triggers, attributes, dynamics-crm

I am trying to create a plugin that triggers whenever the attribute "actualend" of an activity (e.g. a task) changes.

When I mark a task as closed, an "Update" message is being processed. In a plugin registered for the Update of a task only the following attributes are set in the "Target" InputParameter: activityid, modifiedby, modifiedon, statecode, statuscode.
This is the case for PreOperation, as well as the PostOperation.

After the update the "actualend" attribute has been set. But I can find no way to trigger a plugin (or a workflow) when "actualend" changes.

Any ideas how to trigger a plugin or workflow when "actualend" changes?

Comment: did you try update message as trigger and filtering attribute as actualend. this should trigger your plugin only when actualend field is updated/changed. If this does not work you will have to fire on update of modifed on date and then add preImage and posImage and compare if actualend field is changed or not

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Exactly what you propose is one part of the problem. My plugin is registered for the message "Update". If I add "actualend" as filtering attribute the plugin does NOT get triggered - even though the attribute value DOES change when marking the task as closed.
If the plugin runs in Post-Operation, I can see the modified actualend-value - not in the InputParameter "Target", but only in the PostImage.